# How do I write to a file from a servlet-filter and read it in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, servlet-filters

I want to write to a file from my filter and then be able to read it in Eclipse to make sure I've written to it correctly.

This code compiles and runs fine, but I don't know where I can go to read the file or if I've even written anything at all.

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    System.out.println("filter invoked");

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String inPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/template.txt");
    String outPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/output.txt");
    in = new FileInputStream(inPath);
    out = new FileOutputStream(outPath);

    OutputStreamWriter outstream = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    outstream.write("hello");


    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The files template.txt and output.txt are in the WEB-INF directory. I have verified that reading from the files works fine but I can't verify writing to them. Each time I write to output.txt there is still no change to the file.

What am I not understanding about writing to files in the web-application environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close your stream (which will flush it as well) (do that in a `finally` block). Btw you can use [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) `FileUtils` or [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Files` which will make the handling of files easier

However, the general practice is not to write files in the webapp directory, because you will lose them on the next redeploy. Choose/configure an external location to store them.

Comment: I closed the file in a finally block. I refreshed the directory tree of my project. I opened /WEB-INF/output.txt and it is still blank.

Comment: did you try the fileutils / guava option?

Comment: Actually, I gave up. The output file was just temporary anyway, so I simply used a StringBuilder instead. I don't know why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 1):

Also do not forget to wrap it into try finally block.

```
OutputStreamWriter outstream = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
try {
    outstream.write("hello");
} finally {
    outstream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below and let the try with resources to handle the stream

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        System.out.println(httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println(httpRequest.getRequestURI().toLowerCase().endsWith("/v2/api-docs"));
        ByteArrayPrinter pw = new ByteArrayPrinter();
        // here i create a response wrapper
        HttpServletResponse wrappedResp = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() {
                return pw.getWriter();
            }

            @Override
            public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
                return pw.getStream();
            }

        };
        System.out.println("before chaingin");
        // i get the response data from the stream
        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, wrappedResp);
        byte[] bytes = pw.toByteArray();
        String respBody = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println("in if" + respBody);
        if (httpRequest.getParameter("group") != null) {



            byte[] newByte = pw.toByteArray();
            String newString = new String(newByte);
            System.out.println("new string:" + newString);
            // i make a modification in the stream
            String s = newString.replaceAll("basePath", "Vijayy");
            System.out.println("printing s" + s);

            // here i try to write to a file with the modification
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/static/openAPI.json"))) {
                System.out.println("comin in if");
                fos.write(s.getBytes());


                FileCopyUtils.copy(
                        new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/static/openAPI.json")),
                        response.getOutputStream());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // FileCopyUtils.copy(, out);

            // IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(newString.getBytes()), response.getOutputStream());

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(httpRequest, wrappedResp);
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            response.setContentLength(respBody.length());
            response.getOutputStream().write(respBody.getBytes());
        }

         return;
    }
```

ByteArrayprinter is a wrapper I created for the PrintStream for my use case. Again that needed not be considered in your case